# Многооконное приложение с рецептами страв

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Хочу создать многооконное приложение с рецептами страв. По типу каталога страв. Там будет более 10 000 страв. Как мне уместить все эти стравы в одном приложении? Не создавая вручную более 10 000 окон View Controler. Тоесть как перенести рецепты с интернет облака в одно приложение?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, пишите пожалуйста по-русски, в русском языке нет слова `страва`, пришлось лезть в словарь чтобы понять что вы вообще имели в виду ("кушанье, блюдо"). Во-вторых, ваш вопрос очень объемный, поэтому здесь можно дать только общие рекомендации.

1. Вам не нужны тысячи экранов, достаточно двух - выведите рецепты в один список с помощью `UITableView` и по нажатию на пункты выводите на отдельном экране (для этого нужен всего один вью контроллер) подробную информацию о них. Советую обратить внимание на `SwiftUI`, там подобные типовые задачи делаются очень быстро и лаконично.
2. Вы не написали в каком облаке хранятся рецепты, для популярных облаков есть свои библиотеки, через которые можно получать информацию из них. Возможно, если у вас много информации, подгружать ее лучше по частям.
3. Работу над подобным приложением следует проводить по частям - разберитесь, как выводить информацию в таблицу, как переходить между экранами (навигация), в каком виде хранить полученную информацию, как ее получать. Здесь обычно задаются конкретные вопросы, если что-то не получается.